# Listview.ItemDrag files handling

Tags: vb.net, listview, event-handling

I am creating a repository for files I use daily at work, using a TabControl to hold multiple ListView holders. I have managed to create the Drag-Drop functionality from inside the ListView to outside my program using the following code inside the ListView.ItemDrag event handler:

```
Dim fileFullPath As String
Dim mySelectedItem As ListViewItem = lvTools.SelectedItems(0)
Dim dropList As New StringCollection
'DataObject requires a StringCollection
Dim DragPaths As New DataObject()

fileFullPath = Path.Combine(ToolsDirectory, mySelectedItem.Tag)

Try
    'The fileInfo is created because it lets the DoDragDrop be faster
    Dim fileToDrop As New FileInfo(fileFullPath)
    dropList.Add(fileFullPath)

    DragPaths.SetFileDropList(dropList)
    DoDragDrop(DragPaths, DragDropEffects.All)
Catch FNTE As FileNotFoundException
    MsgBox("File could not be found: " & fileFullPath)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Do you have any idea how could I copy the contents of the .txt files instead of copying the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, please refer to the following code for solution:

```
If File.Exists(fileFullPath) Then
    Using tr As TextReader = New StreamReader(fileFullPath)
        Dim fileToDrop As New FileInfo(fileFullPath)
        dropList.Add(fileFullPath)

        DragPaths.SetFileDropList(dropList)
        Dim filecontent As String = tr.ReadToEnd()
        DoDragDrop(filecontent, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End Using
End If
```